# Is code wrapped in a "DEBUG" preprocessor conditional stripped for release builds?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm referring to code similar to this:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Some code with sensitive account information used for debugging
#endif
```

In this case I'm using the precompiler flag to easily load my debugging account information without having to type it every time.

My concern is whether the sensitive account information will be included in any form on the "RELEASE" build.

My understanding is that in this case the chunk of code will simply be stripped before compiling (Assuming of course that the DEBUG flag isn't set for the release configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `DEBUG` flag isn't set in a release build then any code inside `#if DEBUG` and `#endif` will not be compiled into the resulting app.

You can verify this by looking at the build output. Look at the detailed command line used for your source files. If you can't find a `-DDEBUG` in the command then you know `DEBUG` isn't there and that code won't be included.

Comment: I see, thanks, then I guess it's safe to assume that my built IPA can't be reverse engineered or anything to reveal the debug account information?
By the way, is it "-DDEBUG" with double D what I should look for? or is that a typo.

Comment: Nope two `D`. It's the `-D` command line followed by `DEBUG`. So not a typo. And yes, anything inside `#if DEBUG` is completely stripped out before the code is even compiled.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying that!